# Bathroom sink drainage

Tags: bathroom, drainage, overflow

Yesterday I tried to get my bathroom sink to drain   better and I used a plunger. Unfortunately water got into the overflow and now   water  is coming out through the hole.

What can I do?

[image]

...

Comment: I am not able to understand your question.  Please be more specific in your description and I believe a photo will help.  You mention that water is coming out through "thi hole" and I assume you mean "the hole" but WHAT hole?  The overflow??  Then why do you say "hole at bottom of the bathroom sink"??

Comment: @Nicky- I dont think thats an overflow opening (I may be wrong). Give us a photo from above the sink looking down at it. Try and get the entire basin in view. thanks.

Comment: If water is coming out of that hole on the bottom as shown in the picture, then something is broken internally. I think that hole is only for casting of the lavatory and should not be connected to the overflow path. Are you sure water is coming from that hole and not from around the drain?

Answer (score 1):

When you plunge a sink with an overflow built into it you must first plug the opening with a plastic bag so a vacuum is created.

The overflow and the drain are connected when the sink is designed. Sometimes if plunging won't open the drain removing the trap and checking for obstructions is best.

If the clog isn't in the trap by removing it you can than peer down the drain from above at the sink. The stopper lever is also a location that is notorious for causing clogs.

Lastly, if you verify there are no clogs along the exposed drain line and plunging doesn't help, an augured drain snake pushed into the pipe gong into the wall may be your last hope.

I don't recommend any type of clog dissolver or acidic solutions to open the drain as they can do more harm to the pipes and septic system than good.